# Whats my IPv4 address if i only see my IPv6 on whatsmyip

Tags: redirects, ipv6

I am trying to have my website redirect to my computer which I am going to host a Team speak server on. However I cannot see what my IP address so I am unable to redirect it there.

Comment: That *is* your ip address. That's where we're all headed.

Comment: Check out http://ip4.me/

Answer (score 1):

These days it's very probable that you don't have your own IPv4 address anymore. You might be sharing an IPv4 address with other customers of your ISP, which means you can't host anything on it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have alluded to, an IPv6 address is not the same as, or correlated to, an IPv4 address. They are different domains containing different data. You can have an IPv6 address without ever having an IPv4 and vice versa.